# Calculate remaining time

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm developing a quiz system that have a countdown. I've a following table structure:

```
----------------
Table - Test    
----------------
Id - int
RemainingTime - time(3)
LastAnswer - datetime
```

Note: difference between "remaining time" and the "last answer" will not be greater than one hour.

On each user interaction, the "remaining time" will be decremented using a sql like:

```
update Test set LastAnswer=GETDATE(), RemainingTime=RemainingTime - (GETDATE() - LastAnswer) where Id=@id;
```

This code worked correctly in sql server 2008, but in sql 2012 no longer works.

Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Not sure whether SQL Server 2008 supprot `DATEADD()` and `DATEDIFF()` functions

```
   UPDATE Test 
      SET LastAnswer=GETDATE()
         , RemainingTime=DATEADD(minute,-DATEDIFF(MINUTE,LastAnswer,GETDATE() ),RemainingTime )  WHERE Id= @id;
```